# How to use an already defined function in .each(function) traversing

Tags: jquery, each

The following code works fine if xml is a content of some xml file:
it finds 'event' elements and alerts a concatenation of its subelements's content (name + loc).

```
$(xml).find('event').each(function(){
       var name = $(this).find("name").text();
       var loc =$(this).find("loc").text();
       alert(name + loc);
});
```

I would like to separately define the function, which applies to each event element.
Something like this but it is a wrong way:

```
$(xml).find('event').each(procNode(this));

function procNode(this){
       var name = $(this).find("name").text();
       var loc =$(this).find("loc").text();
       alert(name + loc);
}
```

How can I do it in a correct way?
Unfortunately all examples of .each() I got from google have function defined inside .each().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly pass the `this` reference to that function.

Try,

```
$(xml).find('event').each(procNode);

function procNode(){
       var name = $(this).find("name").text();
       var loc =$(this).find("loc").text();
       alert(name + loc);
}
```

And by the way you are calling that function inside of the `.each()` function call, you just need to pass the `reference` of that function only.

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly!
Yes, my main mistake was calling the function procNode() instead of giving a reference.